# Better way to handle linux kernel packet routing

Tags: c, linux-kernel, routes, network-protocols, packet

Here is the scenario -

1. I have two interface wlan0 and test0(logical).
2. I have no control over wlan0 device driver and I have full control over the test0 device driver(xD).
3. test0 actually sends some packet using wlan0 (internally)
4. wlan0 has no associated ip but test0 has

So now when I try to send ping command to any device connected to wlan0. The packet reaches the target device and target device responds with ping response. The packet is receive at wlan0 and pushed to the ip protocol. But ip protocol drops the packet as there is ip protocol associated with wlan0 while trying to route the packet inside kernel.

So, I naively changed the ip protocol routing decision (without affecting normal decision) by adding a clause like below -

1. if there is no ip associated with cur dev && cur dev != test0 then goto 3 else goto 4
2. route the packet and goto 5
3. set dev = test0; and goto 1
4. drop the frame
5. finish

So, now I can send and receive packets but this solution is not good because for every protocol which I want to support in the given scenario, I must add the clause (e,g ARP).
So, my question is what should be the better way/approach to handle packet routing in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can bridge these two interfaces & assign a single IP address to the bridge interface. So the machines connected to the wifi should be reachable via the interface test0.

Comment: unfortunately this won't help in my situation (already tested) as test0 adds some extra header before relaying the packet through wlan0 so the device without test0 can send packet to device with test0 but the reverse is not true as the receiving device in the latter case will discard the packet.